# customizing p-dropdown angular

Tags: css, angular, primeng

Am working on an angular UI.

In the UI , i have added a **dropdown** using **p-dropdown**.
Now the UI look like below

[image]

**Existing css**

```
.p-dropdown {
    width: 150px;
    border:none;
    background: #F5F9FC;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 19px;


  }
  
  
  .p-dropdown .p-dropdown-label{
    color: #0098F3;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
```

I need to remove the extra space after the arrow.

How can i do it.Am not familiar with CSS and UI designs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe that's not the only existent CSS on your dropdown. You should open the developer tools that Google has (right click on mouse + Inspect), and from there, look for a `display: flex` on your `p-dropdown`, since it looks like it is using flexbox